# how to get valid profit center values

Tags: abap, sap-erp

a small report program requires me to enter profit center group values.How can i view the valid values of profit center groups .i picked up a few values from cepc tables that are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `SETNAME` from the table `SETLEAF` with a `SETCLASS` value of '0106'.

To narrow down the results you can specify a Controlling Area in the `SUBCLASS` field or a Profit Center in the `VALFROM` field.

Source: http://forums.sdn.sap.com/message.jspa?messageID=8647500

Answer (score 0):

You can use transaction KCH3 to display profit centre groups if you're just looking for some valid values.